# cosine similarity between two words in a list

Tags: python, word2vec

I am defining a function which takes a list of words and returns information about the words in the list that have non-zero, cosine similarity between each other (along with the similarity value).

Can anyone help me out with this. I was thinking if I can get a precomputed word2vec vector file then it would be very helpful,but there is none on the internet.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ has pointers to several precomputed vector collections for download.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define these two functions

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]
```

and use them as in this example

```
>>> a = 'safasfeqefscwaeeafweeaeawaw'
>>> b = 'tsafdstrdfadsdfdswdfafdwaed'
>>> c = 'optykop;lvhopijresokpghwji7'
>>> 
>>> va = word2vec(a)
>>> vb = word2vec(b)
>>> vc = word2vec(c)
>>> 
>>> print cosdis(va,vb)
0.551843662321
>>> print cosdis(vb,vc)
0.113746579656
>>> print cosdis(vc,va)
0.153494378078
```

BTW, the [`word2vec`](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) that you mention in a tag is quite a different business, that requires that one of us take a great deal of time and commitment for studying it and guess what, I'm not that one...

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining it so easily.. but I have a doubt can't we do the same thing like what we do for a query and document.. I mean to say first find the letter frequency for a letter and then find inverse word frequency. After that calculate the cos angle?.. Just curious to know..

Comment: No, what I've shown is done at a lexical level, the real stuff, say `word2vec` or the `python` free library [`gensim`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html), work at the semantic level. If I were you I'll try investigating and eventually studying the `gensim` library, that's a Python shell built over `word2vec`

Comment: okay.. well the instructions I am reading for my code says " Write a function that takes list of words and returns information about
the words in the list that have non-zero cosine similarity between each other, along with the similarity value. " 
So does this mean semantic similarity or just the normal one that you have suggested?

Comment: this "distance" appears to be in the wrong direction. higher distance should mean dissimilar, and lower similar.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(word2vec(a),word2vec(b))
```

You can use word2vec library for that.