# Python: Check if the sentence contains any word from List (with fuzzy match)

Tags: python, text-mining, fuzzy-search

I would like to extract keywords from a sentence given a list_of_keywords.

I managed to extract the exact words

```
[word for word in Sentence if word in set(list_of_keywords)]
```

Is it possible to extract words that have good similarity with the given list_of_keywords, i.e cosine similarity between two words is > 0.8

For example, the keyword in the given list is 'allergy' and now the sentence is written as

'a severe allergic reaction to nuts in the meal she had consumed.'

the cosine distance between 'allergy' and 'allergic' can be calculated as below

```
cosdis(word2vec('allergy'), word2vec('allergic'))
Out[861]: 0.8432740427115677
```

How to extract 'allergic' from the sentence as well based on the cosine similarity?

Comment: Since you know which word you are comparing to the set, why don't you put a threshold check on the _returned_ value of `cosdis` and get the word if the returned value is greater than the threshold?

Comment: Post your `cosdis()` method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485365/10447069

Comment: It sure does! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]


list_of_keywords = ['allergy', 'something']
Sentence = 'a severe allergic reaction to nuts in the meal she had consumed.'

threshold = 0.80
for key in list_of_keywords:
    for word in Sentence.split():
        try:
            # print(key)
            # print(word)
            res = cosdis(word2vec(word), word2vec(key))
            # print(res)
            if res > threshold:
                print("Found a word with cosine distance > 80 : {} with original word: {}".format(word, key))
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Found a word with cosine distance > 80 : allergic with original word: allergy
```

**EDIT**:

one-liner killer:

```
print([x for x in Sentence.split() for y in list_of_keywords if cosdis(word2vec(x), word2vec(y)) > 0.8])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['allergic']
```

Comment: exactly what I meant :)

Comment: The feeling is mutual :) BTW, although your function `word2vec` does what is required, OP might be using [this word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

Comment: @RickM. not really, OP mentioned the same methods in the comments! I just guessed right! :p

Comment: Many thanks for the codes and idea (@RickM. ). It helps a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
senectence = 'a severe allergic reaction to nuts in the meal she had consumed.'
list_of_keywords = ['allergy','reaction']
word_list = []
for keyword in list_of_keywords:
    for word in senectence.split():
        if(cosdis(word2vec(keyword), word2vec(word)) > 0.8):
            word_list.append(word)
```

---

or if you only want to extract words based of the keyword 'allergy'

```
[word for word in Sentence if cosdis(word2vec('allergy'), word2vec(word)) > 0.8]
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance of the words have to be checked against all the keywords and will be included only when the threshold is reached for any of the keywords. I put in an extra condition in the original list comprehension with a nested list comprehension that does exactly this.

```
def distance(words):
    return cosdis(word2vec(words[0]), word2vec(words[1]))

threshold = 0.8
keywords = set(list_of_keywords)
matches = [word for word in Sentence if word in keywords and 
           any([distance(word, keyword) > threshold for keyword in keywords])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer