# why do i get different result of cosine similarity when compare to library result

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity, edit-distance

i try to compute the similarity of two words using cosine distance ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484529/cosine-similarity-between-two-words-in-a-list)).
this is the code :

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]
```

the similarity is 0.1889822365046136 when i called:

```
cosdis(word2vec('tahu') , word2vec('tempe'))
```

when try to compare with the result of similarity using library (gensim word2vec) the result is different (for example the difference is 0.2). why is that?
this is how i get the similarity using library:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
modelword2vec = Word2Vec.load("/idwiki_word2vec_300.model")
modelword2vec.similarity('tahu' , 'tempe')
```

the similarity is 0.21785985

Comment: This character-based representation, while it is a 'vector' derived from a 'word', it isn't really what the 'word2vec` algorithm is about. But, can you make it clearer in your code (1) what library calculation functions you're applying, and their results for your test input; (2) what your code returns for those same test inputs? Also, not sure your `cosdis()` matches usual definitions of 'cosine distance', and also keep in mind that 'cosine distance' and 'cosine similarity' are related but distinct: the 'closest' words approach `1.0` cosine-similarity, but `0.0` cosine-distance.

Comment: oke i already edit in the question how i called the library to compute similarity.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to expect these to be the same. Nothing about their internals is similar.

The `word2vec()` function you've shown, copied from some other confused SO answer, is not what people usually mean by 'word2vec'. It calculates some counts of characters in a word – which doesn't seem useful to me, but whatever.

The `cosdis()` is likely similarly confused; maybe it's effecting a real cosine-distance calculation of a word where each dimension is a count of characters. (Note that any such 'vector' would have a maximum of 26 dimensions, one for each letter.) But a better approach would be to turn the `cw` counts into an actual `array` type, as in from the popular `numpy` library, then use an explicit & reliable library implementation of cosine-distance.

On the other hand, your `gensim` code shows loading a real `Word2Vec` model that's presumably been trained on real text. It will thus have dense, learned semantic vectors for each word – often of 100 or more dimensions each, which have absolutely nothing to do with the counts of characters in each word.

When you ask that model for the `similarity()`, it will perform a cosine-similarity calculation on those full vectors. Note that cosine-similarity and cosine-distance aren't the same thing.

Your character-based 'vectors' aren't the same in construction/shape/internal-values as the vectors for words in the other model: so even if `cosdis()` was actually an accurate implmentation of cosine-similarity, you still wouldn't get matching values.